# (vqmod) Error: Could not load language total/sub_total

Tags: opencart

I have moved my Opencart website to a new host, and I receive the error:

> Notice: Error: Could not load language total/sub_total! in
>   .../vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_library_language.php on line 41

How do I resolve this?

I have tried renaming vqmod/xml to vqmod/xml.bad, with no result.

I have tried renaming /vqmod/vqcache to /vqmod/vqcache.bad, with no result.

**Update:**

In \system\library\language.php, I commented out an else branch which resulted in an application exit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probable reason can be that you are missing one of the following file:

```
catalog/language/english/total/sub_total.php
admin/language/english/total/sub_total.php
```

if you are missing them, upload them from a fresh copy of opencart and then try.

and put back that `else` , error will be error, not displaying error will not solve it

Answer (score 1):

The most logical explanation for this is that the language file you need is missing. This isn't necessarily the `english` language one if you have multiple languages so you will need to validate them all

Check that the language files

```
admin/language/language-name-here/total/sub_total.php
```

exists if you receive this in the admin area, or

```
catalog/language/language-name-here/total/sub_total
```

if it's on the customer side

The other possibility is that the file is simply corrupt, in which case I would recommend just re-uploading all of these files from a clean copy. Note that the vQmod reference is simply because vQmod has altered the language load file (this is standard for vQmod to do for it to work). If you don't have any modifications that specifically alter the way languages work, this isn't going to be the cause of the error

I believe there was a bug in earlier versions of 1.5.X that caused this kind of problem too, so if you're not on a reasonably recent version I would recommend an upgrade as well